# Setting a pathname as an alias in the .bashrc file

Tags: bash

I'm attempting to use aliases in the .bashrc file to store the paths I commonly go to (Ubuntu 14.04) i.e. `alias pathname="/home/Dommol/test/next"`  But when I attempt to use the alias `cd pathname` I get an error `-bash: cd: pathname: No such file or directory`.

Question:
How do I get bash to recognize that I am trying to use the alias `pathname` and not trying to change to to the directory `pathname`?

As an aside, I could make the alias `alias pathname="cd /home/Dommol/test/next"` and just type `pathname` to change

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`alias` is used to alias a command, not a shell variable. To do what you want, set a shell variable in your `.bashrc`:

```
pathname="/home/Dommol/test/next"
```

Then at the prompt:

```
$ cd $pathname
```

Using an `alias` to make a custom command with the arguments you want this in your `.bashrc`, as you noted in your "aside":

```
alias pathname="cd /home/Dommol/test/next"
```

Then at the prompt:

```
$ pathname
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer by lurker should be the accepted solution. However, to answer your original question, I think, this could work:

```
#Your test code:
alias pathname="/home/Dommol/test/next"
cd pathname

#Similar functionality
ln -s /home/Dommol/test/next pathname
cd -P pathname
```

If you have more such directories & want to cd from any location, you could have this: (Note that this code below is limited to `cd` command.)

```
mkdir -p ~/.cdpath #Random name - could be changed
export CDPATH=~/.cdpath

ln -s /home/Dommol/test/next ~/.cdpath/pathname
cd -P pathname #Will work from any starting location.

ln -s /home/Dommol/test/next2 ~/.cdpath/pathname2
cd -P pathname2 #Will work from any starting location.
```

Best solution would be to create it as a variable, as already explained by lurker's answer. That solution will work for other commands as well.